# Price function gives incorrect results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using excel PRICE function to calculate bond price. My manual calculations show a bond price of 1008.56 which makes sense because `c>YTM` hence `price>par`. Using PRICE function, however, i get a result 932 which is incorrect. what might be the problem? In my excel example: PRICE(settlement date, maturity date, coupon rate, YTM, par(1000), semi-annually)

[image: IMG:]

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio yes, thank you for the question! PRICE(settlement date, maturity date, coupon rate, YTM, par(1000), semi-annually)

Comment: What are the formulas in the `discounted` column?